# Python program compilation issue

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Process finished with exit code 0” in the course of running a Python file with JetBrains PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.

Code:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        print("A dog is created")
def sit(self):
            print(self.name + "has sitten")

        dog = Dog("Rex", 4)
        print(dog.name)
```

Nothing compiles except for “Process finished with exit code 0” message generated by PyCharm
I have an IntelliJ IDEA installed on the same PC and it works fine so I guess this is not an antivirus blocking related issue.
Could you please advise?
Thank you in advance

Comment: What were you expecting to compile? Python is not a compiled language. `exit code 0` means it was successful.

Comment: Double-check the indentation of your code. It was fixed in an edit but most probably it was the source of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python classes don't do anything unless you instantiate them. In this case you're declaring your `Dog` class with an `__init__` method which does a few things (including printing), but this only a declaration - an instance of the class hasn't created so the `__init__` function hasn't run yet.

Assuming that you're looking to get things working within a single file, I would suggest adding the following to the bottom of your file:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dog = Dog()
```

This will cause a new instance of the `Dog` class to be created when the script is run, you should then see your print statements output to the console.

If your code is indented in the way shown in the original question, then the problem is with the indentation. Currently almost all of the code is sitting within the `Dog` class, and not at file-level, so it won't be running when the script is executed, your formatting would need to look like this:

```py
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        print("A dog is created")

    def sit(self):
        print(self.name + "has sat")

dog = Dog("Rex", 4)
print(dog.name)
```

Comment: The problem is to do with indentation.

Comment: Yes, I realised that was a potential problem after writing my answer. I've updated it to reflect the indentation problem too.

Comment: Wait, was it the indentation or not? I just fixed indentation in your question assuming it was just mis-pasted, which is common. Both when writing Python code and asking StackOverflow questions about Python please make sure to keep your indentation consistent as it is very important. As you're using an IDE it should help manage most indentation automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This is an indentation problem as Daniel explained. Ident the code appropriately:

class Dog:
    def **init**(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        print("A dog is created")

```
def sit(self):
    print(self.name + "has sat")
```

dog = Dog("Rex", 4)
print(dog.name)
print(dog.age)`enter code here`